# Using the font joylide, can I stretch curly bracket and rotate?

Tags: rotating, brackets

Can I make my curly bracket so it will be under the whole ax^2?

```
% !TeX TS-program = lualatex

\documentclass[border=0cm,beamer,crop]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots,tikz}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}
\usepackage{fontspec}

\setsansfont{joylide}

\begin{document}
    
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \node at (0,0) {$f\text{(}x\text{)}\text{ = }a\cdot x^{\text{2}}\text{ + }b\cdot x\text{ + }c$};
        \node[scale=0.4, blue] at (2.5,-0.2) { Førstegradsleddet};
        \node[scale=0.4, orange] at (-0.7,-0.6) { Andengradsleddet};
        \node[orange,rotate=90] at (-0.7,-0.3) { \text{\{}};
        
        \node[scale=0.4, red] at (1.2,0.5) { Konstantleddet - Skæring med y-aksen};
        \node[scale=0.4, gray] at (-1.2,0.5) { (Afhænger af $x$)};
        \node[scale=0.4, gray] at (-1.2,0.7) { Den afhængige variabel};
        
        
        
        \draw[->,red] (0.4,0.5) to[out=180,in=90] (0.27,0.25);
        \draw[->,blue] (1.1,-0.2) to[out=180,in=270] (0.88,0);
        \draw[->,orange] (-0.7,-0.5) to[out=70,in=270] (-0.4,-0.25);
        \draw[->,gray] (-1.2,0.38) to[out=-35,in=100] (-0.7,0.2);
        
        
        
    \end{tikzpicture}   
\end{document}
```

Comment: I don't have the font so I can't really test but is that relevant at all?

Comment: Yes, because I'm making somtest look like handwriting with that font and I would like it all to be in that font, also when I rotate the { and make I go under some text.